# Angular errors when running karma tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Im just getting started with Karma for unit testing my JavaScript. This is for an app that uses Angular which is now causing me problems.

Having ran `Karma Init` to create my karma.conf.js file, I've now tried to run a basic test using

```
Karma Start
```

When I run this I get Chrome popping up but errors in the console window:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/ts-ang-app/public/test-app.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket 4A_Vzzao95ERUW0jS6jg with id 5966397
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 8) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/ts-ang-app/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:1611
```

My karma.conf.js file as as follows:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu May 29 2014 13:10:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon-chai'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
               'public/vendor/angular/angular.js',
               'public/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
               'public/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
               'public/test-app.js',

               'public/app/**/*.js',
               'test/tests/**/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
          'public/app/app.js'
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {

        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

I've searched about but cannot find anything relating to this. I was wondering what could be causing this?

As I say, I'm new to Karma so it could be something really dumb or obvious.

Thanks

Comment: The first error suggests you don't have `public/test-app.js`, do you have this file?